# Using Oracle STANDARD_HASH, reproduce the hash in JAVA

Tags: java, oracle, hash, compatibility

I'm using the STANDARD_HASH('input','SHA256') function within Oracle to populate records with their relative hash values.

This can be reproduced by connecting to Oracle doing:

```
select STANDARD_HASH('1234','SHA256') 
from dual
```

```
Table X    
Column 1, Column 1-hashed    
1234, sha512hashresult    
1234, sha512hashresult    
1234, sha512hashresult    
1234, sha512hashresult
```

**Now whats the question;** What do I have to do in JAVA in order to reproduce exactly the hash values which are produced by STANDARD_HASH in Oracle? Does anyone have experience with this?

Note; For some reason there is no seed on the recommended Oracle hash function. Does anyone know the Default seed or how to figure this out?

**Background:** What do i want to do? Populate the table within Oracle with Oracle-Default-Tools and use a Java program to receive the input, hash it and select the correct record in the table.

**What i don't want**; People who tell me how I can achieve it in a different way, I need it exactly this way otherwise save your time

Comment: Instead of trying to reproduce the function in Java, why don't you just call it from Java using a service let's say(and let it execute on the DB side).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with standard libraries. Use [java.security.MessageDigest](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/Signature.html) with algorithm `SHA-256`:

```
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
...

String input = "1234";        
byte[] hashBytes = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256")
        .digest(input.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
String hash = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(hashBytes);
System.out.println(hash);
```

This prints `03AC674216F3E15C761EE1A5E255F067953623C8B388B4459E13F978D7C846F4`, the same string that `STANDARD_HASH` would return.

As discussed in [How to convert a byte array to a hex string in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655181/how-to-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hex-string-in-java), there are faster ways to convert a `byte[]` to a hex string, but `DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary()` has the benefit of being part of the standard library, and should be fine for most use cases.

Java 17 added [HexFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HexFormat.html) to the standard library, which lets you replace

```
String hash = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(hashBytes);
```

with

```
String hash = HexFormat.of().withUpperCase().formatHex(hashBytes);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your support

Answer (score 1):

If you're fine with using [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/HashingExplained) on the Java side, the following code should produce equal results with Oracle's `STANDARD_HASH`:

```
import com.google.common.base.Charsets;
import com.google.common.hash.Hashing;
...

String input = "1234";        
String hash = Hashing.sha256()
       .hashString(input, Charsets.UTF_8)
       .toString()
       // toString() returns the HEX value as lower-case, whereas
       // Oracle's STANDARD_HASH returns an upper-cased string
       .toUpperCase(); 

System.out.println(hash);
```

This prints out `03AC674216F3E15C761EE1A5E255F067953623C8B388B4459E13F978D7C846F4` which is the same you get in Oracle with

```
select STANDARD_HASH('1234','SHA256') from dual;
```